# Reading an object file

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

I have installed a gcc compiler that is compatible another processor(not the one I am using).
When i use the objdump command to read the object file i get the following,

```
objdump -d one.o
one.o:     file format elf32-big

objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

Where is the problem?
Is this because I am using a gcc compatible with some other processor??
Or is there any other way to read an object file?

Answer (score 2):

The man page of objdump mentions a `-m` flag for specifying the architecture. Maybe it needs that hint to be able to read non native files?

Comment: probably by default it takes the actual architecture instead of ARM or Cortex for example